# MySQL - Consulta con LEFT JOIN muy lenta en un servidor

Tags: mysql, python

tengo una BBDD MySQL 3.23 con más de 40 tablas, algunas con 300.000 registros, que clono diariamente mediante un script python en otro servidor que tiene MySQL 5.5.  Realizo múltiples consultas hasta con 8 LEFT JOIN sin problemas en ambos servidores (Windows) y que apenas tardan 3 segundos en el peor de los casos.

Ahora estoy también clonando la primera en un servidor GNU/Linux Ubuntu con MySQL 8.0 pero en el que las consultas se demoran hasta 5 minutos o no se realizan devolviendo error.  Si la consulta es un simple SELECT pues el tiempo es razonable, pero como tenga una sola línea con LEFT JOIN pues entre 5 minutos o no se realiza. Los 3 servidores son remotos, pero el resto de aplicaciones Web o FTP que cuelgan de ellos no tienen una demora que haga sospechar que la red es el problema.

Incluso he clonado la BBDD en un Xampp local y va igual de rápida que los dos servidores Windows remotos, por lo que pienso que el problema es de la configuración del MySQL de esa máquina Ubuntu que está contratada a un tercero.

No soy el mantenedor habitual de la BBDD, ni experto en MySQL, ¿de dónde puede venir el problema?  ¿De la configuración de alguna de las Variable_name del MySQL?

Saludos.

Comment: Y cuál es la consulta? (inclúyela en la pregunta, como texto) Cuáles son las tablas? (incluye las sentencias DDL con las que las creas, como texto) Cómo son? Cuántos registros tienen?

Comment: A ver, sin ver lo que estas haciendo es un poco complicado dar un diagnostico, pero por lo que comentas, suena a que no estás usando correctamente las keys para hacer los join, o no son indices.

Comment: Sería bueno ver los mensajes de error que dices que da a veces para hacernos una idea de lo que podría estar ocurriendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestros comentarios que me han servido de mucha ayuda, ya que Jnavero al hablar de indices me he dado cuenta que el script que clona la base de datos MySQL entre servidores remotos no copia los PRIMARY KEYS y por eso no ejecuta los LEFT JOIN.  Es decir, no copia el schema de la BBDD.

El siguiente tema es cómo hacer que el script python clone también esta información, ya que está trabajando con SQLAlchemy y Pandas.  Entiendo que ya no pertenece a este hilo preguntar sobre python.

Comment: Añadir que el clonado entre la 3.23 y la 5.5 lo realiza otra persona mediante mysqldump, aunque me dijo que utilizaba el script python que no es cierto y eso me ha confundido y retrasado en encontrar la solución.